# Neo4j expand query is very slow

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j-community-3.3.0, there will be:

- Nodes:20000,
- relationships:72000,
- properties per_node:1,
- properties per_relationship:1

My machine has:

- RAM:16G,
- dbms.memory.pagecache.size:6G,
- dbms.memory.heap.max_size:8G

I want to get all nodes connected to a node and sum relationship properties that related to these nodes and send results to a csv file.I want to do this for all nodes in the database.

I have an index on relationship property-

```
INDEX ON :Amount(AMNT), and a Constraints on node property-CONSTRAINT ON (customer:Customet) ASSERT customer.ACCT IS UNIQUE
```

My query is:

```
 CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (x:Customer) with x CALL
 apoc.cypher.run(\"CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(x,
 {relationshipFilter:'Amount>', labelFilter:'+Customer', uniqueness:
 'NODE_PATH' } ) YIELD path return path as path\", {x:x}) YIELD value
 unwind nodes(value.path) as nodes unwind relationships(value.path) as
 rels  with collect(distinct nodes) as nodelist, collect(distinct rels)
 as rellist,x.ACCT as CustNumber with size(nodelist) as numOfMember,
 reduce(s = 0, r IN rellist | s + TOINT(r.AMNT)) AS totalAMNT
 ,CustNumber where (numOfMember > 100) and  ( totalAMNT > 100000) return
 CustNumber,numOfMember,totalAMNT ","results.csv",{});
```

But query running is very slow and after a long time I get this error:

> Error unmarhaling return header;nested exception
>   is:java.net.SocketException:Software caused connection abort:recv
>   failed

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling your two back-to-back UNWINDS are creating a tremendous number of result records (cross product of every node in the path with every relationship in the path, for every possible path from that expand from all :Customer nodes). Don't do this, you're likely to blow your heap.

Also, I'd highly advise you to PROFILE the inner query on just a single :Customer node and see what's going on, especially how the rows increase in your query.

I'm scratching my head why you're using `apoc.cypher.run()` here to wrap a call to `apoc.path.expandConfig()`. Unless there's a good reason for this, I'd recommend removing usage of `apoc.cypher.run()` completely.

We can also use some alternatives to UNWINDing, using some APOC Procedures for flattening and getting distinct values in collections, and filtering some results earlier to avoid processing records that will only be filtered out later.

Maybe try something like this:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("
MATCH (x:Customer) 
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(x, {relationshipFilter:'Amount>', labelFilter:'+Customer', uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH' } ) YIELD path
WITH x, collect(nodes(path)) as allPathNodes, collect(relationships(path)) as allPathRels
WITH x, size(apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(allPathNodes))) as numOfMember, allPathRels
WHERE numOfMember > 100
WITH x, numOfMember, apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(allPathRels)) as rellist
WITH x, numOfMember, apoc.coll.sum([r in rellist | TOINT(r.AMNT)]) as totalAMNT
WHERE totalAMNT > 100000
RETURN x.ACCT as CustNumber, numOfMember, totalAMNT ","results.csv",{});
```

Depending on your graph, the expandConfig() call may be expensive. You may want to see if you can complete this call and get the number of paths expected within a reasonable time. Try this:

```
MATCH (x:Customer) 
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(x, {relationshipFilter:'Amount>', labelFilter:'+Customer', uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH' } ) YIELD path
RETURN count(path) as paths
```

You may be able to get a more efficient query by using `apoc.path.spanningTree()` (or by using NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness, that would be equivalent) if you only want a single path to each node rather than all paths to each node.